# Display popup (JWindow) inside screen whenever it goes outside of the screen

Tags: java, swing, screen, jwindow

I have created a simple autocomplete composed of `JTextfield` and `JWindow` (as a popup).
Everything works fine except when I display the popup on bottom it goes outside of the screen (see the pictures):
[image]

[image]

Is there a way to make it visible inside the screen always ?

Comment: Check the screen bounds and move it popout upwards/left instead when the popup's position is beyond the screen bounds

Comment: @MadProgrammer thnx for your response, I was wondering, before I create my own function, if there is shortcut to do it :) thnx again.

Comment: No, not really...(or at least that I can remember)